# Caliburn.Micro detect textbox enter with modifier

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, caliburn.micro

I have text box with `AcceptsReturn` enabled. I would like to insert a new line after pressing *Shift + Enter*.
Textbox XAML looks like this:

```
...
AcceptsReturn="True"
cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyDown] = [Action HandleInput($eventArgs)]"
```

And the *HandleInput* method:

```
public void HandleInput(KeyEventArgs keyArgs)
 {
  if (keyArgs.Key == Key.Enter && Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Shift)
   { ...
```

When i press only Enter it should make something with input but it insert new line every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `KeyDown` uses event bubbling which means that the event is first raised on the control, and then its parent, and that parent's parent and so-forth until the event is handled.

When you set `AcceptsReturn` to true, the TextBox control handles the enter keystroke so the event is not "bubbled" to the HandleInput method.

You can use `PreviewKeyDown` instead which uses event tunneling, the opposite of event bubbling.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks.